# How to hide elements coming from CMS Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a function that loads tabs from a CMS page to my webpage.
I am trying to hide a tab if the user is not logged in,If the user is logged in the tab must show.This is part of  my code that populates my tabs.

```
menu.Append("<li class=' " + page.MenuClass + "'><a dataid='" + page.ID +"' title='" + new HtmlString(page.LongTitle) + "' href='" + href + "' " + IDAttribute + redirectAttribute + ">" + page.ShortTitle + "</a>" + descendants + "</li>");
```

so the above gets my tabs and appends it to `menu` what i want to do is when the title is equal to the page.longTitle "Account" it must hide this tab.

this is my function to check if the user is logged in or not

```
function Check() {
    JApi.Services.CheckLoginAccount(function(account) { // so its using an api to check if the user is logged in
        if (account == null) {
            // if the user is not logged in then the title='Account' must be hidden
        }
    });
}
```

is there a way i can achieve this? i tested to check if the above function works so i hide a textbox on the page
for example

```
function Check() {
    JApi.Services.CheckLoginAccount(function(account) {
        if (account == null) {
            $("#txtBox").hide(); //so this gets hidden if the user is not logged in,im just not sure how to get the title "Account" from menu and hide that
        }
    });
}
```

output for Account

```
<li class=""><a dataid="24770" title=" Account" href="/page?pageId=24770&amp;title=-Account" class="sf-with-ul"> Account<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a><ul style="white-space: nowrap; float: none; width: 17em; display: none; visibility: hidden;"><li class=" " style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a dataid="24771" bannerbase="24770" title="Register" href="/page?pageId=24771&amp;title=Register" style="float: none; width: auto;">Register</a></li></ul></li>
```

attempted

```
$('#menu a[dataid="24770"]').closest('ul').hide(); this way hides it using the dataid,which i dont want.


$('#menu a[title="Account"]').closest('ul').hide(); // if i do it this way it doesnt hide
```

attempt 2 based on answer bellow

```
$(document).find('#menu li a[title = "Account"]').parent().hide(); //not hiding
$(document).find(" #menu [title='Account']").parent("li").remove();//not hiding
```

Comment: The "Account" title that you are saying is the `page.ShortTitle` or  `page.LongTitle`?

Comment: try using `$("li a[title='Account']")` instead of `$("#txtBox")`

Comment: @MatheusCuba using longTitle

Comment: @gvmani i tried that,it doesnt work, i thought i would have to bind the menu class with it some how?

Comment: @Sarah can you post the generated html ?

Comment: i added the output that gets shown for Account

Comment: Try `$(document).find("[title='Account']").parent("li").remove();` It should find the right element and remove the `li`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i tried it that way and it didnt work,i updated my question to show my attempts

Comment: There is a space in front of "Account" in your HTML markup... `title=" Account"` Remove it or add it to the jQuery selector.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thank you,i didnt notice that.i just added #menu infront of it and took care of the space and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try find the Element like this:

```
$(document).find('li a[title = "Account"]').parent().hide()
```

Your Element is been created dynamically, so you need to use `$(document).find()`

**Edit**

As @LouysPatriceBessette well said, you need to use `.parent()` too, to hide the whole element, not just the `<a>` tag

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, Thanks!! Edited my Answer

Comment: i tried the above and it didnt work,so i did a test and tried it with dataid example :$('#menu a[dataid="24770"]').closest('ul').hide(); this got hidden.But i dont want to use the dataid so i tried it the same way as follows $(document).find('#menu li a[title = "Account"]').parent().hide() and $('#menu a[title="Account"]').closest('ul').hide(); which doesnt work as well

Comment: thank you! this helped i didnt notice the space which @LouysPatriceBessette pointed out,i just added #menu to the front as (' #menu li a[title = "Account"]').parent().hide()